# How to find the value of a child key whose parent key is not known?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database Structure:

[image]

How do I get the value of a child node for example -L2bWBVKUdppnfC2LZhV?
if I don't know it's parent key. I've seen many examples where orderBy("child
-node-name").equalTo("child-value") is used to do that but I don't think this applies to my case because the child key is present only in this node.

EDIT: I have access to all the parent nodes above the parent node in question and the child key. I just don't have the parent node. is it possible to still get the value of the child node?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read a contents of a single node, you either have to know the names of all the parent nodes that lead up to the child node you want to read, or you have to be able to construct a query that yields the child node you're looking for.

Comment: I have access to all the parent nodes above the parent node in question and the child key. I just don't have the parent node. is it possible to still get the value of the child node?

Comment: Please read my answer again - you need to know ALL the parent nodes.  You can't wildcard.